# Collision and movements not working as expected

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to do an example of collision in Action Script 3. It's a `character` that should stop when it hits a `platform`. It works well when I move only to the right, left, up or down directions, but if I try to move in the diagonals, if the `character`is colliding with the `platform`, the object goes to a different area of the screen.

This is the compiled example: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5282142/GameDemo.html

And below is my code.

Now, does anyone know a better way to do what I am doing, or how can I get the character not to go to a weird position when I try to move it in a diagonal?

```
var level:Array = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < numChildren; i++) {
    if (getChildAt(i) is Platform) {
        level.push(getChildAt(i).getBounds(this));
    }
}

var speedX:int = 0;
var speedY:int = 0;

var kLeft:Boolean = false;
var kRight:Boolean = false;
var kDown:Boolean = false;
var kUp:Boolean = false;

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDownHandler);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onKeyUpHandler);

function onKeyDownHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
    if (event.keyCode == 37) kLeft = true;
    if (event.keyCode == 38) kUp = true;
    if (event.keyCode == 39) kRight = true;
    if (event.keyCode == 40) kDown = true;
}

function onKeyUpHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
    if (event.keyCode == 37) kLeft = false;
    if (event.keyCode == 38) kUp = false;
    if (event.keyCode == 39) kRight = false;
    if (event.keyCode == 40) kDown = false;
}

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);

function loop(event:Event):void {
    moveChar();
    bound();
}

function moveChar():void {
    if (kLeft) {
        speedX = -10;
    } else if (kRight) {
        speedX = 10;
    } else {
        speedX *= 0.5;
    }

    if (kUp) {
        speedY = -10;
    } else if (kDown) {
        speedY = 10;
    } else {
        speedY *= 0.5;
    }

    character.x += speedX;
    character.y += speedY;
}

function bound():void {
    if (character.x > (800 - character.width/2)){
        character.x = 800 - character.width/2;
    }
    if (character.x < (character.width/2)){
        character.x = character.width/2;
    }
    if (character.y > (480 - character.height/2)){
        character.y = 480 - character.height/2;
    }
    if (character.y < (character.height/2)){
        character.y = character.height/2;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < level.length; i++) {
        if (character.getBounds(this).intersects(level[i])) {
            if (speedX > 0) {
                character.x = level[i].left - character.width/2;
            }
            if (speedX < 0) {
                character.x = level[i].right + character.width/2;
            }
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < level.length; i++) {
        if (character.getBounds(this).intersects(level[i])) {
            if (speedY > 0) {
                character.y = level[i].top - character.height/2;
            }
            if (speedY < 0) {
                character.y = level[i].bottom + character.height/2;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using a physics library like Box2D to prevent likely future brain meltdown.

Comment: @PeterSmith I have, I'm trying to use Box2D with Flash CS5.5. I looked up an error that I came across and there seems to be an issue with Box2D and Flash CS5.5. They tell me to compile again the examples, but it won't work. Running the examples contained in the Box2D package should be simple, right?

Comment: I got Box2D to work by following this tutorial that uses WCK: http://gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=135

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Problem lies in this part of your code :

```
for (i = 0; i < level.length; i++) {
        if (character.getBounds(this).intersects(level[i])) {
            if (speedX > 0) {
                character.x = level[i].left - character.width/2;
            }
            if (speedX < 0) {
                character.x = level[i].right + character.width/2;
            }
        }
    }

for (i = 0; i < level.length; i++) {
            if (character.getBounds(this).intersects(level[i])) {
                if (speedY > 0) {
                    character.y = level[i].top - character.height/2;
                }
                if (speedY < 0) {
                    character.y = level[i].bottom + character.height/2;
                }
            }
        }
```

The character does not actually move to a random position. It is being set by you, above.

You have to create a better logic (as per the scenario) where your code should not get confused when two keys are down simultaneously & a collision occurs.

Comment: Thank you, @loxxy . There is another issue, too. By using the `intersects` function in `character.getBounds(this).intersects(level[i])`, it will detect collisions with the movie clip's surrounding area, and not its actual area. I would use `hitTestObject`, but as I am a beginner, I can't think of a logic using that function.

Comment: it's as simple as `if(object1.hitTestObject(object2) == true) {...}`

Comment: You answer is correct and the problem actually lays in there. But I'll just forget about this complexity and use a physics engine. Thank you!